# Recursive unique search in particular sub directories - Perl

Tags: perl, file-io

Here's my directory structure..

```
                                    Current
                   /                    |                       \
           a                            d                       g
        /      \                   /             \              | 
        b       c                e              morning         evenin
       /  \    /   \             |
     hello hi  bad good          f
                                 /  \   
                               good night
```

Where current, a,b,c,d,e, f,g are directories and other are files.
Now I want to recursively search in current folder such that the search shouldn't be done only in g folder of current directory. Plus, as 'good' file is same in current-a-c-good and current-d-e-f-good, the contents of it should be listed only once.
Can you please help me how to do it?

Comment: take a look at `use File::Find`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The suggestion of **Paulchenkiller** in comments is fine. The `File::Find` module searchs recursively and lets to handle easily what to do with files and directories during its traverse. Here you have something similar to what you are looking for. It uses `preprocess` option to prune the directory and the `wanted` option to get all file names.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find;

my (%processed_files);

find( { wanted => \&wanted,
        preprocess => \&dir_preprocess,
      }, '.',
);

for ( keys %processed_files ) { 
        printf qq|%s\n|, $_;
}

sub dir_preprocess {
        my (@entries) = @_; 
        if ( $File::Find::dir eq '.' ) { 
                @entries = grep { ! ( -d && $_ eq 'g' ) } @entries;
        }   
        return @entries;
}

sub wanted {
        if ( -f && ! -l && ! defined $processed_files{ $_ } ) { 
                $processed_files{ $_ } = 1;
        }   
}
```

Comment: As to the second part of the question, determining whether or not two files are the same, that's a bit more interesting. I've typically done this by using `Digest::SHA` to build a unique string for each file, keeping that in a hash, and using that to determine whether I've seen the file before. That's laborious as it involves reading each file twice, but it's accurate for content. It does depend a bit on precisely what you mean by files being the "same" in different directories.

Comment: @StuartWatt: I assumed that two files with same name were iddentical. But it isn't so laborious, instead of saving the file name (`$_`) as key of the `%processed_files` hash, calculate its `SHA`, save it as key and the filename as value. There is no need to read them twice, or did I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

```
my $path = "/some/path";
my $filenames = {};

recursive( $path );

print join( "\n", keys %$filenames );

sub recursive
{
    my $p = shift;
    my $d;

    opendir $d, $p;

    while( readdir $d )
    {
        next if /^\./; # this will skip '.' and '..' (but also '.blabla')

        # check it is dir
        if( -d "$p/$_" )
        {
            recursive( "$p/$_" );
        }
        else
        {
            $filenames->{ $_ } = 1;
        }
    }

    closedir $d;
}
```

Comment: I didn't get that 'next if' part. And where is it checking that file with same name should come only once?

Comment: There is a comment after that. Do you know Perl at least a little?

Comment: It wasn't there at the time  I had asked the question!